# Why does a method in another activity gets called before succesful Firebase signIn?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app uses FirebaseAuth. In my SignInActivity, on clicking the sign in button, the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` `onCompleteListener` starts my DashboardActivity with an Intent. In the DashboardActivity, there is a method which calls `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()` which crashes my app if the user trying to signIn does not exist.
**The question here is:** why does the method get called at all if the Intent was not sent? or was the intent sent?

here is my SignInActivity signIn Button code:

```
signIn.setOnClickListener((new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (!email.getText().toString().equals("") && !password.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            showProgressBar();
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener((new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    hideProgressBar();
                    Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Signed In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            })).addOnFailureListener((new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    hideProgressBar();
                    Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Failed to Sign In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "please fill all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}));
```

DashboardActivity code (that crashes the app):

```
private void queryDB() {
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    Query query = reference.child(getString(R.string.users))
            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .child("securityLevel");
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String secLevel = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            if (secLevel.equals("1")) {
                fab.hide();
            } else {
                fab.show();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: +-+ " + secLevel);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
```

The Logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference
        at com.quwaysim.regapp.DashboardActivity.queryDB(DashboardActivity.java:191)
        at com.quwaysim.regapp.DashboardActivity.onCreate(DashboardActivity.java:60)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127).......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not checking if task is successful or not. You have to do it like:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (!email.getText().toString().equals("") && !password.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        showProgressBar();
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener((new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null){
                    hideProgressBar();
                    Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Signed In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        })).addOnFailureListener((new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                hideProgressBar();
                Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "Failed to Sign In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "please fill all fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

OnComplete will execute even if the authorization passed or not. You need to add OnSuccessListener and handle the intent there.

Comment: I tried OnSuccessListener too, it worked perfectly... Thanks a lot to you too... It's wonderful getting help from you guys